# Image captions in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii

How can I get this in Yii framework using Chtml::link

```
<a href="#" title="Movie 1" class="search-movie"><img alt="Movie 1" src="../../images/1.jpg"><p>Movie 1</p></a>
```

When I did this,

```
<?php $imghtml=CHtml::image('../../images/1.jpg');
echo CHtml::link($imghtml, array('moviepage/index'),array('class'=>'search-movie', 'title'=>'Movie 1'));?>
```

I only got

```
<a href="#" title="Movie 1" class="search-movie"><img alt="Movie 1" src="../../images/1.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the markup for the caption when you generate the link:

```
<?php 
    $imghtml=CHtml::image('../../images/1.jpg');
    $caption = CHtml::tag('p', array(), 'Movie 1');
    echo CHtml::link("{$imghtml}{$caption}", array('moviepage/index'), array('class'=>'search-movie', 'title'=>'Movie 1'));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
<?php $imghtml=CHtml::image('../../images/1.jpg');
echo CHtml::link("$imghtml<p>Move 1</p>", array('moviepage/index'),array('class'=>'search-movie', 'title'=>'Movie 1'));?>
```